# Computation of Error rate in nearest neighbor classification algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-matching, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to find the optimal value of K for K Nearest Neighbor Algorithm.
I am been running this classification method on Matlab for different number of classes members
but I need to calculate the error rate when we use different value of K.
I am trying to use this idea as example:

I have the following data set:

1 3 1

2 3 2

2 1 2

3 3 2

3 4 1

3 3 2

2 2 2

Where the first column is the x axis the second it y axis the third is the label
of the class and I need to classify point (x,y) using K-NN algorithm. I am using different values of K. 
My question is if I know that that point (4,1) is not included in the source dataset 
but I know that it is from the class label 1. How can I compute the error rate of the 
certain K value based on method Leave-one-out-cross-validation.

Thank you a lot in advance

Regards

Rinadi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leave-one-out cross validation means simply, that given your model `m`, training set `T` of size `n` and some evaluation metric (error measure) `E` you proceed as follows:

1. For each point `(x,y)` from `T`:

   1. You train your model `m` on `T\(x,y)` (all points but the one taken in 1.)
   2. You check `E( m , (x,y) )`, for example you check whether `m` is able to determine `y` given `x` correctly (then `E`=0) or not (and `E`=1)
2. You compute the mean of all `E` values across all points analyzed

As the result you have a mean generalization error estimation - you checked how well your model can predict a label of one point, trained on the rest of the training set.

Comment: I face an issue for this implementation because it takes so much time if you have the training dataset very huge. My implementation has a very high complexity. Is there any divide and conquer implementation for your algorithm instead of doing it for every single point should we better divide that into a set of points.
Regards

Comment: This is not "my implementation" this is a **definition** of leave-one-out method, and there is no other way around. This method is a border case of the general n-folds cross validation, where you split data into n equal size chunks, and n times test your model on one chunk, and train on the whole rest. if you take n=size of data you get the leave-one-out strategy. One of the most common choices is n=10 (train on 90% test on 10%)